# Ghost Edit Markdown Output

Tags: html, node.js, ghost

I have a template where the images are full width & the post content is wrapped in a container. The container sets the width of the content but the image is full width and in a separate container. I was hoping that in Ghost I could wrap the markdown image with some sort of code to end a wrapper and what not. Heres the code output i'm trying to achieve:

```
<div class="container">

  <p>Something</p>

</div>

<div class="blog-post-image">

  <img src="image" />

</div>

<div class="container">

  <p>Something</p>

</div>
```

I was hoping I could add some code so that Ghost would add output the image markdown code something like this:

```
</div>

<div class="blog-post-image">

  <img src="image" />

</div>

<div class="container">
```

Is this possible? I would add the code into the posts manually but I don't then want to in 6 months change the template and have to edit a load of posts.

Answer (score 0):

you can include parts of HTML in your MD, so just create some in your article where you need to special format anything

Comment: Yea how do you do that? I'd know how to do it in Wordpress, you'd just do a regular expression but i'm new to Ghost

Comment: http://support.ghost.org/markdown-guide/ here is the guide and is stated there: All HTML is valid Markdown. If you’re stuck not able to format your content how you would like (for example using tables) you can always use plain HTML instead of Markdown.

Comment: I don't think you got my question. I need to edit the output of the image markdown